# CSS selectors ::v-deep, /deep/ and >>> not working on GitHub pages, but locally they do

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to implement a typer animation using: https://github.com/cngu/vue-typer
The problem is that on GitHub Pages the text remains black and no style rule applies to it, but locally it works with `deep` selectors.

I have followed the docs and applied styles like so:

```
  .vue-typer .custom.char.typed {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

But this did not work.

So I have added:

```
  ::v-deep .typed {
    color: #fff;
  }
  /deep/ .typed {
    color: #fff;
  }
  >>> .typed {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

I have tried all of them together and separately. The text always remains black on GitHub Pages.

My page template looks like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <section>
   <article>
    <div>
     <p>
      <vue-typer>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you try `::v-deep > .typed`

Comment: Nope. I made it work by removing `lang="css"` from the `style` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept:

```
::v-deep .typed {
    color: #fff;
}
```

and made it work by removing `lang="css` from the `style` tag which looks like this now:

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep .typed {
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```